# Apache JMeter - find out how many requests are possible

Tags: apache, performance, webserver, load-testing, meter

I am searching for a solution to test, how many requests my webserver could handle, until causing a load-time of more than 5s. Is there a possibility to manage this with Apache jMeter?

Server: SLES OS running a WordPress blog(Apache Webserver, MySQL)

Best regards
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is. Example action plan:

1. Record anticipated test scenario using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)
2. Perform correlation (handle dynamic values) and parametrization (if required)
3. [Add virtual users](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users). It is recommended to configure users to arrive gradually, like starting with 1 and adding 1 each second. You can use [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which provides an easy visual way of defining ramp-up and ramp-down.
4. Add [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) with the value of 5000 ms so it will fail the request if it takes > 5 seconds
5. Use [Active Threads Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) and [Response Times Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) listeners combination to determine what maximum amount of users which can be served providing response time < 5 seconds.

Comment: Hey Dmitri, thanks for your detailed answer. I will try it directly :-)

Comment: I´ve created a test with the following actions:  
  
1. Ultimate Thread Group:
- Start Threads Count: 100
- Initial Delay, sec: 0
- Startup Time, sec: 30
- Hold Load For, sec: 60    
- Shutdown Time: 10
2. Duration Assertion:   
Duration: 5000ms   
3. Active Threads Over Time:   
- config not needed?   
4. Response Times Over Time:  
- config not needed?   
5. HTTP Request Defaults:  
Server name: wordpress-blog.com/  
Port 80  
Is it enough / is something missing? I can´t see the result inside the listeners :(

Comment: You're missing the most important one: [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) %)

Comment: hmm I already set up the http request defaults with server name and port. Isn´t it the same which you mean?

Comment: Could you look over my template please? I´ve uploaded it to Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ak3k0n6ah23wrpl/5sek.jmx?dl=0

Comment: How many times do I need to repeat that you **need** to add HTTP Request Sampler?